# Classx is not abstract and does not override abstract method methodx(java.lang.Object) in Interfacex

Tags: java

http://pastebin.com/m64305b4

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public class ListGraph<N> implements graphs.Graph
```

to

```
public class ListGraph<N> implements graphs.Graph<N>
```

You're implementing a generic interface, so you have to provide the piece in the angle brackets. (sorry, brain gone blank, can't remember the exact terminology)

Comment: "type parameters (also called type variables)" http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `@Override` annotation to the `addNode()` implementation in `ListGraph`:

```
@Override
public void addNode(N node){
    nodes.put(node, new ArrayList<ListEdge<N>>());
}
```

Comment: He doesn't have to. It's just convienient to do so, cause compilator can tell you if you try to override something incorrectly